# Ho to read artifacts downloaded in one stage to the next consequence stage in Yaml Pipeline in Azure

Tags: azure-devops

If you see my Yaml below, I have $(Build.SourcesDirectory) which has artifacts which I am downloading and copying it in Azure Blob. In Next Stage I would like to make use of $(Build.SourcesDirectory) contents, but I am not getting anything if I call $(Build.SourcesDirectory) in my next stage. Why is that happening and how can I fix this??

```
     - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          displayName: 'Publish PS'
          inputs:
            targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\flow_ps
            artifactName: 'Flow_Tools_PS'
        - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
          displayName: Download Flow CodeGen
          inputs:
            artifact: 'Flow_Tools_PS'
            path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Flow_Tools_PS'
        - task: AzureFileCopy@2
          displayName: 'Publish Flow_Tools_PS to Blob'
          inputs:
            SourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Flow_Tools_PS'
            azureSubscription: 'Azure CICD'
            Destination: AzureBlob
            storage: '$(BlobStorageAccount)'
            ContainerName: '$(BlobContainer)'
            BlobPrefix: '$(BlobPrefix)/$(DeploymentVersion)/Flow_Tools_PS'
            AdditionalArgumentsForBlobCopy: '/V /S'
            outputStorageUri: BlobUri
            outputStorageContainerSasToken: BlobSASToken
        
  - stage: PublishFlowNotebooks
    dependsOn: Flow
    jobs:
      - job: DevOpsScripts
        pool:
         vmImage: 'windows-latest'
         environment: 'Flow'
        steps:
        - checkout: DevOpsScripts
        - powershell: |
             Get-ChildItem $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -Recurse
          name: DebugCheckout
          displayName: Debug script checkout

        - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
          inputs:            
            buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
            targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
          inputs:
            targetType: filePath
            filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ReleaseNoteScripts/UploadWithReleaseNotes.ps1'
```

Comment: Jobs can run on different agents or even on entirely different servers, so you can't depend on the results from one job being available for subsequent jobs. You either have to `checkout` the source code again, or publish an artifact and `download` it. Refer to the YAML pipeline documentation for more details.\

Comment: i already have a repo to be checked out which i am doing. can I checkout multiple directories. so in this case you are saying me to checkout Build.SourceDirectories

Comment: Hi @ZZZSharePoint. Is there any update about this ticket? If Krzysztof Madej's answer could solve this issue, you may consider accepting it as answer. This will be helpful to other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share some directories between jobs you should publish content of that directory:

```yaml
steps:
- publish: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  artifact: Flow
```

and then on the next job download this artifact:

```yaml
steps:
- download: current
  artifact: Flow
```

Be aware that

> By default, files are downloaded to $(Pipeline.Workspace)/. If an artifact name was not specified, a sub-directory will be created for each downloaded artifact.

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

And if you want to [checkout multiple repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) this is possible

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
  - repository: MyBitbucketRepo
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitbucketServiceConnection
    name: MyBitbucketOrgOrUser/MyBitbucketRepo
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository # In a different organization
    endpoint: MyAzureReposGitServiceConnection
    type: git
    name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyGitHubRepo
- checkout: MyBitbucketRepo
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository

- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```